# adding HOG Features in a matrix "matlab"

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction

**After extracting HOG features of folder of images, I want to add all this results in one matrix. How I can do this? this is my code in matlab:**

```
% Get list of all jpg files in this directory
% DIR returns as a structure array.  You will need to use () and . to get
% the file names.
%to get all images in Motorbikes directory

imagefiles = dir('Motorbikes/*.jpg');      
nfiles = length(imagefiles);    % Number of files found

for ii=1:nfiles
   currentfilename = ['Motorbikes/',imagefiles(ii).name];

   currentimage = imread(currentfilename);
   images{ii} = currentimage;
end

%To extract features of each image
featureMatrix = [];

for jj=1:nfiles
    currentImageFeatures = extractHOGFeatures(images{jj});

    featureMatrix = [featureMatrix, currentImageFeatures];
end
```

Comment: `featureMatrix = [featureMatrix, currentImageFeatures];` Like this?

Comment: is `currentImageFeatures` always of the same size? You seem to already put everything in the same matrix `featureMatrix`, concatenating horizontally. Perhaps you want to concatenate vertically so that each row contains a single features vector?

Comment: yes it is always the same size, each image features concatenated horizontally.
But i want them to be each image features in one row.

Comment: Image features in one row does not make sense to me. But if you still want it that way just change `featureMatrix = [featureMatrix, currentImageFeatures];` to `featureMatrix = [featureMatrix; currentImageFeatures];`.  (Notice the semicolon)